# Send Parameters to WebPage

Tags: javascript, html, objective-c

I'm trying to use iOS Native app send a few(`getWidth()`, `getHeight()`, `getSourceUrl()`) parameters to the webpage. I found [this](https://github.com/marcuswestin/WebViewJavascriptBridge) is useable, but I don't know how to fix this problem?

The webpage template (this template works on android) is as below:

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"/>
    <title>auto skip</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.onload = function(){
            var width = window.javaControl.getWidth();
            var height = window.javaControl.getHeight();
            var imgUrl = window.javaControl.getSourceUrl();
            var imgElH = document.getElementById("img_content_h");
            imgElH.width = width;
            imgElH.height = height;
            imgElH.src = imgUrl;
        }

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <img id="img_content_h" alt="" />
</body>
```

I use this code, but it doesn't work!

```
[self.bridge callHandler:@"getWidth" data:[NSNumber numberWithInt:320]]; 
[self.bridge callHandler:@"getHeight" data:[NSNumber numberWithInt:64]];   
[self.bridge callHandler:@"getSourceUrl" data:@"http://211.155.89.163:28080/FlowKit/uploads/userinfo/20150527/C47F1DC39A31443ACF4EAF3802F06879.png"];
```

Comment: I use these code, but it doesn't work!    [self.bridge callHandler:@"getWidth" data:[NSNumber numberWithInt:320]];

    [self.bridge callHandler:@"getHeight" data:[NSNumber numberWithInt:64]];

    [self.bridge callHandler:@"getSourceUrl" data:@"http://211.155.89.163:28080/FlowKit/uploads/userinfo/20150527/C47F1DC39A31443ACF4EAF3802F06879.png"];

Comment: All information relevant to the question should be provided within the question itself. Please edit to add information instead of posting them as comment. Also, please clarify on what is *this* problem. Are you getting any errors? If yes, include the error message in the question itself.

Comment: Thanks Harry  .I have solved this problem ,I'm sorry there is no clear description of the problem before  , because I don't understand JavaScript how to work.I understand that I can not just according to the current web template and I must init the webpage and addEventListener like the [link]https://github.com/marcuswestin/WebViewJavascriptBridge author tell us.